# Some simple questions to ask about jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I am learning jQuery. If I have the following html code on my page:

```
<div class="transport car">
  <button type="button" class="car" >car</button>
</div>
```

I have the following two questions:

1. In jQuery, what does selector `$('.transport.car')` refers to? the whole ***div*** or the ***button***??
2. Is `$('.transport[name]')` refers to the element with class 'transport' and MUST have name attribute?

Comment: to give parent and child the same css class is abusing css :)

Comment: This is really a css question more than a jQuery one.  If you're confused by the selectors, any ole css reference online will help you.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In jQuery, what does selector `$('.transport.car')` refers to? the whole `div` or the `button`??

The `div`. It selects an element that has both, the `transport` **and** the `car` class. To select the button, you would have to add a space: `$('.transport .car')`. Now it is the [*descendant selector*](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/).

> Is `$('.transport[name]')` refers to the element with class `transport` and MUST have `name` attribute?

Yes. But the attribute can be empty.

---

The selector syntax is basically the same as the one of CSS. jQuery just adds some custom selectors.

[**Btw. you can easily test this yourself.**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/Wqm5a/)

Comment: How about if there is a space between like: $('.transport  [name]'), does this refers to the child element of .transport which contain 'name' attribute?

Comment: @Leem: Yes, but not only children, all descendants.